# Using a non 3-way bulb in a 3-way lamp

Tags: light-fixture, safety

I bought a lamp that I see needs a 3-way bulb. I don't really know what that means, but I see that the switch turns three times. Is using a regular bulb in it dangerous?

Comment: By the way, GE makes a most exceedingly excellent 3-way bulb. It is LED and is "150W equivalent" at the high setting.  The trick is, it switches Low-High-Medium, which means if you put it in a simple 1-way socket, you get full brightness.   Not cheap but the quality is so good that you only have to buy it once.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Most of the time**, with most 3-way sockets and most "one-way" light bulbs, it's fine, other than you click a few extra times to turn it on and off.

**Some of the time**, due to manufacturing tolerances and the like, there can be a problem with the contact for the intermediate ring shorting out as you switch through the 3-way settings. It's *not terribly common*, but I have seen it happen more than once.

Comment: But other than shorting you have not seen any fires or anything of that sort?

Comment: does doing this, cause any light flickering issues? and how often do you see this "some of the time shorting issue" ?

Answer (score 6):

a three way bulb has an extra filament and provides 3 brightness levels, if you use a regular bulb it will work ok, but only give one brightness level.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-way_lamp

Comment: Sounds like a brake light lamp for a car, where there is one ground and two live connections, each connected to a filament of different brightness.